# Взятие адреса у массива

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Всем известно что имя массива это адрес первого элемента в массиве, но все было бы так просто если бы не взятие адреса у имени массива.

Есть такое объявление массива: `char array[] = "String";`

Если мы пишем: `array` или `&array[0]` - мы получаем адрес первого элемента в массиве первый вариант - неявный, второй - явный.

Я подумал хм, а что если я напишу `&array` - на первый взгляд ничего странного адрес тот же что и у `array` или `&array[0]`, но если чучуть закопаться по-глубже, то есть `&array+1` - мы увидим что адрес увеличится на длину строки (для меня это странно, никогда этого не видел, кроме как в параметрах, когда аргументом был указатель на массив элементов определенного количества, прям как сейчас)

Интересно есть ли альтернатива такому поведению (`&array`)? Я пока что додумался до такого способа: `(char (*)[sizeof(array)])array` - но правильно ли это?

Помимо этого интересно следущее поведение:
Если мы пишем `*array` мы получим элемент массива ровно как и `array[0]`, но если мы напишем `*(&array)` - мы не получим элемент массива, мы получим тот же самый адрес, который указывает на первый элемент, но с той лишь разницей что его адресаная арифметика упала с целого массива до одного символа.

Можно ли сказать что в данном случае это разименование указателя до уровня указателя на символ (такой своеобразный даунгрейд указателя)?

И что вообще происходит с массивом когда мы пишем `*(&array)` на ваш взгляд?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас есть указатель вида

```
T *p;
```

то 1) для арифметики указателей используется значение `sizeof( T )`, и 2) разыменование указателя дает `lvalue` , на который указывает указатель.

Например, если имеется следующий фрагмент кода

```
int a[] = { 1, 2 };
int *p = &a[0];
```

то значение указателя после выполнения выражения `++p` будет равно

```
значение указателя перед инкрементом плюс значение sizeof( int )
```

В этом случае в результате указатель будет указывать на элемент `a[1]`.

Если имеется объявление следующего массива

```
char array[] = "String";
```

то оно эквивалентно следующему объявлению массива

```
char array[7] = "String";
```

Если ввести typedef объявление

```
typedef char T[7];
```

то объявление вышеприведенного массива можно записать также как

```
T array = "String";
```

Поэтому чтобы объявить указатель на этот объект, следует записать

```
T *p = &array;
```

И, как показано выше, для арифметики указателей для указателя `p` используется выражение `sizeof( T )` , которое равно `sizeof( char[7] )`.

Разыменовывая этот указатель, вы получите `lvalue` объекта типа `char[7]`

Это легко проверить, выполнив предложение

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( *p ) );
```

результатом которого будет значение `7`, то есть получена длина массива типа `char[7]`.

Однако когда в качестве объекта, полученного после разыменования указателя, имеется массив, то он в выражения за редким исключением преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент.

Из стандарта C (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Поэтому для вышеприведенного примера если выражение `*p`, не используется в качестве операнда оператора `sizeof` или оператора `&`, то происходит неявное преобразование полученного массива в указатель на свой первый элемент. Поэтому, например, выражение `**p` даст объект типа `char` со значением `'S'`.

Comment: `typedef char string[];
string a = "Hello World\n";
string *ptra = &a;
printf("%p - %p\n", &a, &a+1);
printf("%p - %p\n", ptra, ptra+1);`

Comment: почему в последнем printf я получаю `error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds`, хотя в предыдущем printf то же самое

Comment: @MaximPro Что означает "ошибка выхода из массива"? ptra - это указатель на неполный тип. Поэтому арифметика указателей не применима.

Comment: @MaximPro Тип char[] - это не полный тип, то есть размер этого массива неизвестен. Поэтому и указатель на этот тип  является указателем на неполный тип. Невозможно вычислить адрес следующего объекта, не зная размер текущего объекта.

Comment: Ага спасибо, я думал что размер автоматически был определен после инициализации массива строкой

Comment: Кстати почему `char a[] = "Hello World\n";` автоматически будет вычислено? А так нет: `typedef char string[]; string a = "Hello World\n";`?

Comment: @MaximPro Потому что в первом случае число элементов массива определяется по числу инициализаторов.

Comment: Нет для первого случая понятно, не понятно почему с вариантом typedef не вычисляется

Comment: @MaximPro А что должно вычисляться? Объявлен указатель на неполный тип.

Comment: Ну допустим когда идет строка `string a = "Hello World\n";` тут должно бы посчитать сколько инициализаторов

Comment: @MaximPro Здесь подсчитало. Но не имеет отношению к объявлению типа указателя.

Comment: Ой, точно, что-то я сплю...по идее тогда так делать неверно как я написал `string *ptra = &a;`?

Comment: @MaximPro Компилятор не сможет, исходя из типа указателя, применить к нему арифметику указателей.

Comment: Я так понимаю это не запрeщено, но языком поведение не определено когда `typedef char string[]; string *ptra;`?

Comment: @MaximPro Объявляется указатель на неполный тип. Так как размер типа адресуемого объекта неизвестен, то компилятор не может выполнить арифметику указателей.

Comment: Вы писали тоже самое сверху, я это понял, нет смысла писать дважды тоже самое

Answer (score 4):

```
char array[] = "String";
```

Тип `array` - это `char[7]` - массив из 7 символов.
Соответственно, `&array` - указатель на массив из 7 символов.
Значит, `&array+1` - указатель на *следующий* массив из 7 символов. Ну, а `*(&array)` - это массив из семи `char` (грубо говоря, то же, что и `array`).

*"По-моему, так".* (с) Пух